# Why insert a double <span> tag in <button>?

Tags: xhtml, button, html

Sometimes, I found too many people like to insert a <span> tag in a <button> tag. Sometimes, they place two <span> tags. I want to know, why do they do this?

Comment: I can't wait to see how many text browsers render all the text as a button...

Answer (score 1):

CSS is supposed to allow separation between content and style. Unluckily, when you need a complex design you often need to alter your HTML markup so you can apply the necessary CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this with `<div>`. That's done for styling (double borders), but it's also done to handle IE bugs ([box-border model bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug)).